# drop down list validation without a form

Tags: jquery, list, validation, drop-down-menu

OK,  I have been researching drop down list form validation and cannot find anything that does what I am looking for.  My dropdown list is part of a list element and not a form element, and my submit button is an "add to cart" href.  what I am looking for is a way to display an error message if the user does not select a size option from the "select" group. everything else i've seen references a form in the jquery code, is it possible I can just use the class of the selector instead of an id? and can the error code fire only when a user tries to click "add to cart"? Note: I have several products in this store and a list element is set up for each product with it's own "add to cart" button.  see my html.  I don't have any jquery code because I am all over the place as to what to do.

```
<li class="product" name="some dress" price="10" 
name1="some dress Size 6 (Option #1)" price1="10"
name2="some dress Size 8 (Option #2)" price2="10"
name3="some dress Size 10 (Option #3)" price3="10"
name4="some dress Size 16 (Option #4)" price4="10"> 

<a class="product-image" href="images/catalog/someimage.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto" title="some text about product">

<img src="images/catalog/someimage2.jpg" width="180px" height="150px" alt=""/>
<div class="text-overlay">
<p class="product-heading">some description:</p>
more description about product here
</div>
</a>
<p> <span class="product-heading">Designer:</span>some designer name</p>

<!-- options for buy button -->
<select class="product-options">
<option value="" selected disabled>Select</option>
<option value="1">Size 6</option>
<option value="2">Size 8</option>
<option value="3">Size 10</option>
<option value="4">Size 16</option>
</select>

<a href="#" class="product-buy" option="product-options">Add To Cart</a>
<div class="product-price"><span class="product-currency">$</span>10</div>
</li>
```

Comment: Yes, everything you mention is possible. Bind a `click` event to your button(s) and check the value of the `select` with jQuery.

Comment: can you clarify? I'm a novice with jq....

Answer (score 2):

See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LMzu5/8/)

```
$(".product-buy").click(function()
                        {
                            var sel = $(this).prev().val();
                            if(sel=="" || sel==undefined)
                            {
                                alert("Please select size");
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: weird, it works in your demo, but not on my site, do u think the jquery version may have something to do with it? my site currently is using 1.7.1.min instead of 1.9.1 in your demo?????(i'm grabbing at straws ;)...

Comment: If you have more than 1 more than one product on a page then this will not work since your selector will get all `product-options`

Comment: only my 2nd time using stack overflow...what or where is team viewer?

Comment: yes, I do have more than one product on the page, quite a bit, actually, that thought did cross my mind, hence my note in my initial question "Note: I have several products in this store and a list element is set up for each product with it's own "add to cart" button.

Comment: @NikolaMitev now I am getting an error in inspector (jquery-1.7.1.min.js:3Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #) and it's not doing what your demo is doing so something is haywire in my code somewhere else.

Comment: just go to the line that error raised. I didnt use hash sign (#) in code above.

Comment: im ready to pull my hair out, now, @NikolaMitev, error is gone in inspector, but js code still not doing what it did in your demo, I probably just need to hire someone to do it, I am very new with js, i have some php knowledge, and of course html5 but i think this just may be above my pay grade -_-

Comment: HAAAAAAA-LE-LEU-YAH! got it to at least give me the error pop up! had the js in the header, moved it down with all my other dr scripts and it worked(gave me the error popup like your demo), but it still adds the product to the shopping cart.  I would like it not to do that until a size is selected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the value of the `select` using the [jQuery prev](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) method to get the previous select list. The code below will make sure something except the first option is selected.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ytwzA/1/)

```
$('.product-buy').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $size = $(this).prev('.product-options');
    if ($size[0].selectedIndex <= 0) {
        alert('Please select a size');
    } else {
        alert($size.find('option:selected').text() + ' added to cart');
    }
})
```

Comment: yeah, this didn't work either for me. what it is doing is adding the product to cart, with all the information except the size.  before it would add the product in the cart as "undefined", and no errors are showing up in inspector

Comment: post up the js you are using

Comment: <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>